# I want to create a plot using plot function but faced with an error

Tags: r

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values In addition:
> Warning messages: 1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs
> introduced by coercion 2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min;
> returning Inf 3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max;
> returning -Inf

[i want to compare class with nuclear and mitochondrial diversity using a plot but not able to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUGpA.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility using `tidyverse`, although I'm unsure exactly what you want the output to be.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-class, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = class, y = value, colour = name), size = 3.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

Output

[image]